# "To tell the truth" vs "to tell you the truth."

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

What's the difference between the two? Which one is more common? When should I use the former and then the latter?

Comment: to tell you the truth, to me sounds as if I have been chosen for the truth to be told.

Comment: They may have completely different meanings, depending on context. You should probably refine your answer to provide some. (I think I know what you're looking for, but we shouldn't have to guess about that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of **semantics**, there is no difference. Both sentences mean the same.

In terms of **usage**, I've heard "to tell the truth" more often than I've heard "to tell you the truth"

Comment: It's just a longer form. Since the subject is first person, the addressee of this verb of speaking is by definition second person, and is thus deletable, like the agent of a passive or the experiencer of a flip sense verb.

Comment: “To tell you the truth” is less efficient but definitely sounds more native. Neither, however, sounds as native to me as “To be honest”.

Comment: Is "to tell you the truth" appropriate for an article (written material)? For a technical article?

Comment: @x-yuri   Yes, but "to be honest" sounds more idiomatic.